# py2exe - FATAL ERROR: Could not locate script

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

When I generate a script in py2exe, it generates the exe but when I open the exe, I am presented with this error:

```
Could not locate script resource: The specified 
resource type cannot be found in the image file.

FATAL ERROR: Could not locate script
```

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup
import py2exe
import sys

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(console=['program.py'])
```

And here is the what the command prompt pops out when I run the command to generate the exe (python setup.py py2exe):

```
running build
running py2exe

  6 missing Modules
  ------------------
? pkg_resources.extern.appdirs        imported from pkg_resources
? pkg_resources.extern.packaging      imported from pkg_resources
? pkg_resources.extern.six            imported from pkg_resources, pkg_resources.py31compat
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
Building 'dist\program.exe'.
error: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect.
```

I am searching all over the place but can't find the answer.

Thanks, 
Peppa

**EDIT:** I honestly don't know if this is a problem of py2exe or something is wrong internally in my python installation or operating system. I welcome all advice and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

In your `setup.py` you have two lines of the format `from foo import setup` - this will result in a conflict. What happens if you strip this `setup.py` back to the minimal example provided in the [Tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)?

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['program.py'])
```

If that doesn't help, it suggests the problem may lie in your environment.

Comment: I tried the example you gave and it still gave me the "FATAL ERROR: Could not locate script" error. If you can, can you go a little bit deeper on what you mean on how the problem lies in the environment? Thanks.

Comment: An environment problem could be that it genuinely can't find the modules / files that it needs (as suggested by the `6 missing Modules` statement in your `python setup.py py2exe` output). It looks like your `py2exe` command is failing due to this, and as such even if a `.exe` is being generated, I wouldn't expect it to run (and you may find that the `.exe` is not being generated and you're just running an old version).

Did the output of the `python setup.py py2exe` change with the change to `setup.py`?

Comment: Nope, it just shows the exact same message as i mentioned in my question

Comment: I honestly still don't know what the problem was but now all of a sudden is started working. I know this is not a technical answer/comment but, it's working so, yeah. Thanks for all the help! I really do appreciate it!